# How do I add Environmental Variables to a React App's Docker image deployed with Google's Cloud Run?

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I want to be able to provide a list of values that get used as Environmental Variables while a ReactJS application (built as an image with Docker) is running with Google's Cloud Run. This list of values (which are not secrets) should not live in my project (as a file), and should be "easily" modifiable.

Is there any way I can do this?

---

I've read enough to know that **it is not possible to read Environmental Variables in a standard React Application** because the page is pre-rendered when the NodeJS application is built. [The ReactJS documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) says it very clearly:

> The environment variables are embedded during the build time.

So the easy idea of using Environmental Variables out of the box is discarded.

There is [this very nice post](https://dev.to/dsample/environment-configuration-with-react-nginx-3ja5) that explains the issue very well, talks about alternatives, and even suggests a solution that involves NGINX, but that is not what I'm looking for. Therefore the next best thing would be to be able to parametrize the values so that they can be changed whenever my React App's Docker image is built.

So how do I provide Environmental Variables to Docker, while I submit a build to GCloud, so that when then React App is built, it fetches those environmental variables?

It would seem that the solution would involve passing my values as parameters to the `gcloud builds submit` command, but I'm not sure how to turn the parameters into Environmental Variables.

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
# build environment
FROM node:21-alpine as react-build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

#Using NPM instead of yarn
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And this is the command I use to submit my builds to Google: `gcloud builds submit --tag some-image-name:latest`

I don't have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file, so I'm assuming that Google is using some default, but I don't know its contents.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer mixing a bit of the ideas of:

- [The post I mentioned before](https://dev.to/dsample/environment-configuration-with-react-nginx-3ja5)
- [Google Cloud's Substitution documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values)
- [This example `cloudbuild.yaml` file supplied by Google](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/main/run-example-builddeploy/cloudbuild.yaml).

The following is the solution I was able to come up with.

First, update the `Dockerfile` to receive some arguments (`ARG`) and store them as environmental properties (`ENV output input`):

```
# build environment
FROM node:21-alpine as react-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./

ARG MY_PROPERTY_1
ARG MY_PROPERTY_2

# React environmental variables are needed during the `npm build` phase,
# because this is a static application (no server side logic).
ENV REACT_APP_MY_PROPERTY_1 $MY_PROPERTY_1
ENV REACT_APP_MY_PROPERTY_2 $MY_PROPERTY_2

#Using NPM instead of yarn
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

# server environment
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
RUN sh -c "envsubst '\$PORT'  < /etc/nginx/conf.d/configfile.template > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf"
COPY --from=react-build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Secondly, create the `cloudbuild.yaml` file to allow for parameters to be substituted when submitting a build. You need to make sure that both of docker's `build` and `push` steps are executed, and this is our chance to provide arguments to the `Dockerfile` using the `--build-arg` argument in combination with Google's Substitution (`${_SOME_VARIABLE}`):

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '--tag', '${_IMAGE}:${_TAG}', '--build-arg', 'MY_PROPERTY_1=${_MY_PROPERTY_1}', '--build-arg', 'MY_PROPERTY_2=${_MY_PROPERTY_2}', '.']
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', '${_IMAGE}:${_TAG}']
images:
  - '${_IMAGE}'
```

(You'll need to supply the Image's Name and Tag as Substitutes because the `submit` command won't allow for both a `--config` and a `--tag` to be arguments at the same time...)

Now you can finally use the following command to submit your builds (don't forget to substitute variables with the `'_'` prefix):

`$ gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml --substitutions="_IMAGE=<image name>,_TAG=<tag name>,_MY_PROPERTY_1=property1,_MY_PROPERTY_2=property2"`

Finally, it is just a matter of substituting the `<...>` placeholders with your actual values, for you to configure different Environmental Variables for ReactJS to read.

The solution is far from perfect, but given the limitations of a ReactJS Client side application, it is good enough.

⚠️ **DISCLAIMER:** Do NOT do this if you intend for the Environmental Variables to be secrets!!! Remember that the values will be fully visible on the browser!